# PL/pgSQL Performance Profiling

Tags: performance, postgresql, profiling, plpgsql

I want to improve the performance of some **PL/pgSQL** stored procedures (I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3).
I used *pg_stat_statements* extension to isolate and improve the atomic SQL statements, and now most of the execution time of the procedures is not mapped to SQL statements anymore. In other words, it seems like my bottleneck is the overhead of the language.

My main procedure invokes in a for-loop (in this case 31478 times) *add_link()* procedure. The total time of *add_link()* is **21.7 seconds**. Each *add_link()* invokes *calc_link_count()* with a total of **11.5 seconds** (out of 21.7).
But, the most expensive SQL statement takes overall **1.5 seconds** (out of 21.7!).

How can I profile the procedures to understand better where is the time invested?
Is there a profiling tool to map the bottlenecks?

Thanks!

Main function which invokes *add_link()* in a loop 31478 times:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_added_links() RETURNS SETOF linkwithvalidationresult AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    link RECORD;
BEGIN

    FOR link IN (SELECT * FROM linktovalidate) LOOP
        PERFORM add_link(link.linkid, link.objid);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM linkwithvalidationresult;

END
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

*add_link()*, which invokes *calc_link_count()* (overall 21.7 seconds):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_link(link_id uuid, object_id uuid)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    features_broken_count integer = -1;
    src_id uuid;
    dst_id uuid;
    linkschema_id uuid;
BEGIN

    -- Most expensive SQL statement - 1.6 seconds overall
    SELECT sourceobjectid,destinationobjectid,linkschemaid INTO src_id,dst_id,linkschema_id FROM link WHERE objid=link_id; 


    -- Calculate broken features count
    features_broken_count := (SELECT calc_link_count(src_id,dst_id,linkschema_id));

    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION add_link(uuid, uuid)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

*calc_link_count()* procedure (overall 11.5 seconds):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_link_count(src_id uuid, dst_id uuid, linkschema_id uuid)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    features_broken_count integer = 0;
BEGIN

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM groupmembercount WHERE groupid=src_id)) THEN

    features_broken_count := features_broken_count  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT notallowedfeatures FROM linkschema_notallowedfeatures WHERE linkschema_objid=linkschema_id
    AND notallowedfeatures IN (
    SELECT features FROM featurespreset_features JOIN dleobjectderef ON featurespreset=featurespreset_objid WHERE objid=dst_id)) AS cnt);

    features_broken_count := features_broken_count  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT requiredfeatures FROM linkschema_requiredfeatures WHERE linkschema_objid=linkschema_id
    AND requiredfeatures NOT IN (
    SELECT features FROM featurespreset_features JOIN dleobjectderef ON featurespreset=featurespreset_objid WHERE objid=dst_id)) AS cnt);

END IF;

RETURN features_broken_count;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: While PL/PgSQL is not fast, it's not _that_ slow either. On my system a trivial PL/PgSQL function that loops 31478 over a simple `insert` runs in 286ms. I think you'd better show the function source code, otherwise it'll be pretty hard to help you. Maybe you're doing lots of logic and conditionals? Or perhaps `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` blocks?

Comment: Oh, and AFAIK there's no particular pl/pgsql profiling tool. You can always use `perf` or `gprof` at the platform level, profiling the whole PostgreSQL server *including* PL/PgSQL, but you'll need to know a lot more about the mechanics of how the server works to understand the results.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code. I didn't publish the full implementation of *add_link()*, it's enough for me know to understand why the calls to *calc_link_count()* take so much time. I have indexes on fields which I query on, and that's why the most expensive SQL statement takes only 1.6 seconds (for **31K** runs).

Comment: This kind of deeply nested procedural logic will _never_ perform well. You really need to start thinking in terms of set logic. Anyway: While I'm surprised to see the runtime differences you describe it's hard to say anything useful without complete and unmodified code, and quite possibly the data as well. If I had to trace this I'd probably start with auto_explain and pg_stat_statements, as you do, then move on to digging in PostgreSQL's guts with `perf`.

Comment: It might be helpful to add some `raise notice` statements throughout the procedures that emit the difference between the `clock_timestamp()` at the start of the procedure and the `clock_timestamp()` at the current location. See if you can isolate which blocks are taking the unexpected time.